# How i can create a database in xml or xslt or xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Currently I'm working on a project which will be based on xml, xslt or xpath database. I do'nt know how to do this and what to do for this.I had create the xml and xslt files for this but I don't know how to create the database in this. Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have the privelege to comment yet so I write this as an answer. What xml-database are using? To assist you further informations seem to be necessary.

You can check the Wikipedia page for "xml-database" if you haven't pick one yet.

BR